Edge dev tools: Detached Elements "Press Get Detached Elements to begin" not clickable
I am using Edge (123.0.2420.65  (64-Bit)) and want to debug my Angular Application to find detached dom nodes.
I am currently trying to get this tool working, but It does not show any detached nodes even for the example application (https://microsoftedge.github.io/Demos/detached-elements/).
I think the "Get Detached Elements" button on the top left is disabled but I don't know why.
Does anyone have an Idea what I can do?


I just tested this issue on two of my devices with different Edge versions (Edge 123.0.2420.65 and Edge 123.0.2420.81). When I tested according to the steps in the official documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/memory-problems/dom-leaks), I found that the Node List did not appear, but the total number of detached nodes could be displayed.
According to my investigation, you can try to roll back the Edge version to "121.0.2277.128" or before this version, and the Node List can be displayed. Also, you can try using the Memory tool and search for detached elements as an alternative. Specific steps are as follows：
1.Open the Memory tool.
2.Run your scenario of choice on the webpage.
3.In the tool, click Take snapshot to capture a heap snapshot.
4.In the snapshot, type detached in the Class filter text box at the top.
Surely, you can also press "Alt+Shift+I" in the Edge interface to submit feedback.
